# What's the meaning of "topological" in "symmetry protected topological phase"

Tags: topological-insulators

I am trying to understand the symmetry protected topological phase. Most papers only explain the symmetry but none of them explain the meaning of "topological". 
My question is : 
What's the meaning of "topological" in "symmetry protected topological phase"?

Comment: Perhaps this can (partially) answer your question: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/57179/is-edge-state-of-topological-insulator-really-robust. I can provide additional details if necessary.

Answer (score 6):

The follow article directly address your question (which is a very good question):

[Reconciling topological insulators and topological order](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/70728/reconciling-topological-insulators-and-topological-order/72241#72241)

The article explains the different meaning of "topological" in  "topological insulators" and "topological order".